# Mask in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-engine, game-development

i'm learning unity and got issue with my game project. When i try to mask object in editor it works well, but when i compile ,my project and run there was issue, mask don`t work at all.

i search my problem in diferent sites but can't fix it, if some one had the same problem and you somehow fix it i would glad if you share your information with me.

That`s how it works in unity

[image]

and that how it works in compiled game

[image]

I try to make simple progressbar

Comment: what exacttly on the second picture is wrong? it just looks to have a different value set.

Comment: yeah, now i understand. But the difference is that second image, green panel, need to be masked, than objects in both picture will look same.

Comment: @МаксІскандіров Just in case If you want to fix the rounded ends of the slider to be same always (as it gets stretched out in the second picture) you can 9-slice them in the image sprite editor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.